# Raspberry PI 3 B, cannot find usb RFID reader, rc10c-usb-8h10d

Tags: pi-3, rfid

I have Raspberry Pi 3 B board and I was install latest Raspbian image with desktop based on Debian Stretch.

Now, when I connect my usb rfid rc10c-usb-8h10d 125kHz to rbPi3 board on usb, and in command prompt, when I issue command `lsusb`, I get this

```
root@raspberrypi:/dev# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 08ff:0009 AuthenTec, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But when I issue command `ls /dev/` I cannot find any usb.

What should I do? How can I find my RFID usb device?

Am I missing something?

Comment: What makes you think the device will mount on `/dev`? Many of these are hid devices and emulate a keyboard e.g. `/dev/hidraw3`.

Comment: Thank's for replay. I don't know, maybe because RFID is a usb reader. I just want to try this RFID usb reader using RaspberryPi 3 B but I don't know how? (My first steps in raspbian world.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Milliways has right. You should try hidraw0 or similar. Try to observe ls /dev/ when rfid isn't connect and ls /dev/ when rfid is connect to usb.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the script from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144735/106927) which lists USB device files along with human-readable device names:

```
#!/bin/bash

for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && exit
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && exit
        echo "/dev/$devname - $ID_SERIAL"
    )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try a terminal application.

If you scan a RFID tag the reader should respond as if the card number had been typed on a keyboard. Most such devices claim to be readable on Windows.

It should be possible to read input from the specific device, but I have never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

observe the change of the output of this command before and after pluggig in the USB device:

```
ls -lrtd /dev/*|tail
```

it will usually be something like `/dev/hidraw4`