# Connecting Raspberry Pi 4 with USB A Docking Station

Tags: pi-4, usb

I have a docking station, I normally connect it to my laptop (USB-C to USB-A cable => USB-C on the dock and USB-A on the laptop). That works perfectly => I can use an external monitor, which is connected via Display Port with the docking station.

I wanted to connect the dock with my Raspberry Pi 4. USB-A on the Raspberry and USB-C on the dock, but that does not work => monitor shows "no signal"

Is it a driver problem or why doesn't it work?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Your dock is most likely a composition of a USB hub and several devices attached to it internally, including a DisplayPort adapter. You need to find out what this adapter is (using `lsusb` or by parsing `/sys/bus/usb`, either manually or with a script similar to [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122312/33476)), and then figure out what's wrong with it. A missing driver could be one of the reasons it doesn't work.

If the driver is there, check your desktop environment configuration: it may not activate additional displays automatically. I would start by installing the `arandr` package, running the GUI tool it contains (also called `arandr`), and looking for a new display in layout menu.