# Huawei Stick not associated with wwan0

Tags: usb, modem

I have a problem with Huawei LTE stick: MS2372h-153

I have two versions of this stick:

1. Vodafone IoT branded
2. Non-branded

Using the non-branded stick, everything works as expected. I plug it into my raspi 4B running headless raspbian version 10 (buster) and I get a wwan0 after boot and after activating it with AT-cmds I can simply call `dhclient -v wwan0` and I am connected to the internet.

Using the Vodafone IoT branded stick, I do not get the wwan0 interface. I tried with 3 different branded sticks - none was creating the interface. I can still access the stick via serial port and activate it, both on windows and on the raspi, but I do not get the wwan0 interface.
This is my `lsusb` output with the branded stick:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb

    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1596 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0451:bef3 Texas Instruments, Inc.
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT:**
The command `lsusb -t` returns:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 3, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 4, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 5, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 6, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=option, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 3, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
```

Right after plugging in the stick I get:

```
sudo dmesg | grep huawei
[  265.431391] usbcore: registered new interface driver huawei_cdc_ncm
```

So I guess the driver are loaded appropriately.

I do not have installed qmi or similiar additional software for modem handling. I already went through the list of supported AT cmds for this device to change some settings but I am quite new to this modem/AT-cmds setting so I was unsuccessful in making any progress.

I do have two questions now:

1. Any idea, why the branded stick is not associated with wwan0 interface?
2. Any idea, if I can somehow un-brand/reset those Vodafone sticks?

EDIT: I do believe it is simply not possible to change the mode of these branded sticks. I can change the mode of the other sticks (e.g. to storage mode) but these branded sticks have an interface class 255 and the switchusb program expects class 8 to apply the mode change. So I believe they are some kind of locked...

Comment: Try running [this script](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122312/33476) to find out which device file (if any) that stick corresponds to. It could also help to make `lsusb` display the driver name (AFAIK that's `lsusb -t`). And, as always, run `sudo dmesg` right after plugging in the stick and post the output corresponding to that event.

Comment: As to "why", one of the reasons is that branded sticks tend to identify themselves as flash drives (containing Windows drivers for the stick) rather than actual modems, and you need to make them switch to modem mode somehow.

Comment: I have added some more information to the original post to answer some of your requests.

Comment: I tried switching it from 1596 to 1573 mode, although I think both represent modem modes, using: `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1596 -V 12d1  -P 1573 -b 001 -d 004 --verbose -M "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000101000100000000000000"`
The error I get is: `Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0; interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort` 
I wonder if this error tells me that my command actually tries to switch the device into storage mode, though I could be wrong. Besides, I am not sure if the MessageContent "555..." number is correct.